# Flatten 'next' and 'prev' links in a linked list

Tags: python

I have a list of strings that represent data structure traversals. I want to collapse the link list traversals into a more compact representation. To do this I'd like to count the number of adjacent `next` and `prev` links and collapse them into a single integer.

Here are examples of the transformations I want to do:

```
['modules']                                   -->  ['modules']
['modules', 'next']                           -->  ['modules', 1]
['modules', 'prev']                           -->  ['modules', -1]
['modules', 'next', 'next', 'next', 'txt']    -->  ['modules', 3, 'txt']
['modules', 'next', 'prev', 'next', 'txt']    -->  ['modules', 1, 'txt']
['super_blocks', 'next', 's_inodes', 'next']  -->  ['super_blocks', 1, 's_inodes', 1]
```

Each `next` link counts as +1 and each `prev` is -1. Adjacent `next`s and `prev`s cancel each other out. They could come in any order.

I have a working solution to this, but I'm struggling to find a satisfyingly elegant and Pythonic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
def convert(ls):
    last = None
    for x in ls:
        if x == 'prev': x = -1
        if x == 'next': x = +1
        if isinstance(x, int) and isinstance(last, int):
            x += last
        elif last:  # last is not None if you want zeroes
            yield last
        last = x
    yield last
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use a generator:

```
def links(seq):
    it = iter(seq)
    while True:
        el = next(it)
        cnt = 0
        try:
            while el in ['prev', 'next']:
                cnt += (1 if el == 'next' else -1)
                el = next(it)
        finally:
            if cnt != 0:
                yield cnt
        yield el

print list(links(['modules', 'next', 'prev', 'next', 'txt']))
```

It is worth noting that a sequence containing an equal number of `next` and `prev` gets removed entirely. It would be easy to change the code to produce a `0` if that's what you want (I think the requirements are bit unclear on this).

Comment: ['modules', 'next', 'prev', 'txt'] -> FAIL.

Comment: @unbeli: I think that's a big strong. The requirements are unclear for this corner case.

Comment: I think it's quite clear, next/prev should come out as an integer. For that case and your code, they won't.

Comment: Agree. I left the 0 case unspecified because I could go either way with it, put 0 or omit it entirely.

Comment: @unbeli: See the OP's comment above. It spells out the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the most straightforward approach that came to mind.  Straightforward is a valuable quality for understanding, debugging, and future maintenance.

```
def process(l):
    result = []
    count = 0
    keepCount = False
    for s in l:
        if s == "next":
            count += 1
            keepCount = True
        elif s == "prev":
            count -= 1
            keepCount = True
        else:
            if keepCount:
                result.append(count)
                count = 0
                keepCount = False
            result.append(s)
        # end if
    # end for
    if keepCount:
        result.append(count)

    return result
# end process()
```

I do like NPE's use of a generator better, though.  (mine can be converted easily by changing the 'result.append()' to 'yield')  His *(original)* answer is nearly the same as mine, but I include the 0 count in the event that the next/prev tokens are adjacent in equal numbers.

Answer (score 1):

How about a little `reduce()`?

```
def collapse(lst):
    was_link = [False] # No nonlocal in Python 2.x :(
    def step(lst, item):
        val = { 'prev': -1, 'next': 1 }.get(item)

        if was_link[0] and val:
            lst[-1] += val
        else:
            lst.append(val or item)
        was_link[0] = bool(val)

        return lst

    return reduce(step, [[]] + lst)
```